# gulp-useref no me copia los archivos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp

Tengo un problema con gulp-useref. Tengo la siguiente tarea.

```
gulp.task('compre', ['inject'], function () {
   return gulp.src('index.html', {cwd: '/app'})
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Me ejecuta inject sin problema pero `useref` no me genera el archivo en `dist`, tampoco me da error. He visto varios ejemplos en la web y lo hacen igual, que puede ser??

Comment: Tu fichero `index.html` contiene build blocks como los que se muestran en [useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/useref)?

Comment: Hola @devconcept efectivamente, tengo las etiquetas del inject y bower (wiredep) y a esas las acobija la grande que seria build (la de useref). Pero no funciona.